# Proof verification: If $a \equiv b (mod$ $n)$, then $a^3 \equiv b^3 (mod$ $n)$

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

Would someone be willing to verify the following proof?

Theorem: Suppose $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}; n \in \mathbb{N}$.  If $a \equiv b (mod$ $n)$, then $a^3 \equiv b^3 (mod$ $n)$.

Proof:

$a \equiv b (mod$ $n) \rightarrow xn = a - b; x \in \mathbb{Z}$

$\rightarrow a = xn + b$

Then, $a^3 = (xn)^3 + 3b(xn)^2 + 3b^2(xn) + b^3$.

This gives us $a^3 - b^3 = (xn)^3 + 3b(xn)^2 + 3b^2(xn) = n(x^3n^2 + 3bx^2n + 3b^2x)$

$n | n(x^3n^2 + 3bx^2n + 3b^2x) \rightarrow n | (a^3 - b^3)$

Therefore $a^3 \equiv b^3 (mod$ $n)$.

Comment: Your proof is correct!

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
a^3 = b^3 + \color{red}{n}(x^3n^2 + 3bx^2n + 3b^2x).
\end{eqnarray*}
Your proof is sound.

Comment: Thank you to GhD and Donald Splutterwit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

You could have stopped at $a^3=b^3+kn$, it doesn't matter whether $k$ has a complicated expression, if it's an integer, then $a^3\equiv b^3\pmod n$.

However, notice that you can factorize $xn$ actually, and that $xn=a-b$.

Thus $a^3-b^3\equiv(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)\equiv 0\pmod n$ since $(a-b)\equiv 0\pmod n$.

You are not forced to get back to definition everytime, try to use modular calculus directly as well, it is powerful.

Answer (score 3):

The posted proof is correct. It might be even easier, however, to first prove the more general:

$$
a \equiv b \pmod{n} \quad\text{and}\quad a' \equiv b' \pmod{n} \quad \implies \quad a \cdot a' \equiv b \cdot b' \pmod{n}\quad
$$

The proof goes the same: $a\cdot a' = (xn+b)\cdot(x'n+b')=b\cdot b'+n\cdot (x\cdot b'+ x' \cdot b+n\cdot x\cdot x')\,$.

Then, using the proposition with $a'=a, b'=b$ gives $a \equiv b \implies a^2 \equiv b^2 \implies a^3 \equiv b^3 \pmod{n}$.

Comment: you can as well go $aa'-bb'=a(a'-b')+b'(a-b)\equiv 0\pmod n$ or $a^n-b^n=a(a^{n-1}-b^{n-1})+b^{n-1}(a-b)$ by induction.

Comment: @zwim Right, of course. I just followed OP's notation to make the similarity more obvious.

Comment: yes, sorry for not tagging, the comment was essentially addressed to OP as an incentive to explore further :-)

Comment: Couldn't you also generalize using the binomial theorem?  Something along the lines of (very rough sketch):  
Suppose $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}; n, x \in \mathbb{N}$.    
If $a \equiv b (mod$ $n)$, then $a^x \equiv b^x (mod$ $n)$, and therefore $a^x = yn + b^x; y \in \mathbb{Z}$. If we expand $a^x$ via the binomial theorem, we see that the only term not containing $n$ is equal to $b^x$, and therefore $n|(a^x - b^x)$, and $a^x \equiv b^x(mod$ $n)$.

Comment: @sphere Yes, that would work. You could also prove it from the proposition in my answer, since $a^x \equiv b^x$ is equivalent to multiplying $a \equiv b$ with itself $x$ times.